# Is it possible to use right click, scroll, etc. when using the Magic Trackpad on Windows?

Tags: windows, magic-trackpad

I connected my Magic Trackpad 2 to my Windows PC via a Lightning to USB C cable. The only issue is that I can only move the mouse and click. I can not right click or scroll. I also can't use more advanced gestures such as three-finger, four-finger, and force touch gestures.

Is there any way to enable some subset of these trackpad actions on Windows? Some online research suggests it's possible in Bootcamp, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution than installing Bootcamp drivers on my Windows installation.

It also seems like on Windows there is some sort of inertial trackpad acceleration enabled. Is it possible to disable this?